# Applied logratio analysis. Where do you learn it?

Tags: references, compositional-data

I want to analyze compositional data using R. Dirichlet regression has been proposed, but the logratio analysis methods seem to constitute a more complete and well-tested approach, so I want to learn that.

But **where?**

I am not an advanced statistician, just a humble bachelor in maths. I want a complete largely self-contained reference which also deals with applications in e.g. R (I know there is a package called "compositions" in R).

Comment: you can start by searching this site for the tag[compositional-data]  There are some instructive threads.

Comment: Maybe you already know that, but there is the book [Analyzing Composinal Data with R](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642368080) in the _"User R!"_ series.

Answer (score 1):

No issues at all, a math background is very helpful here.

Two books I would recommend:

- For more of a conceptual overview that is more solid on the theory [Modeling and Analysis of Compositional Data by Pawlowsky-Glahn, Egozcue, and Tolosana-Delgado](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1118443063.html). It is a really wonderful book.
- For a very applied book [Analyzing Compositional Data in R by van den Boogaart and Tolosana-Delgado](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783642368080). This is the book that accompanies the "compositions" package in R.